# Getting Recent folders and Recent files in Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net

i wrote some code to get Recent folders and files in C# by using

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(
                          System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                              Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent)).
```

It is working fine in windows 7.But it is not working in windows xp.
Because there is no folder with "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent" in XP.
Then how to get recent files in windows xp?

Comment: This works perfectly. I've done it several times. `Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent` maps to `CSIDL_RECENT`, which returns `C:\Documents and Settings\username\My Recent Documents` in Win XP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows XP, `System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Recent)` will not return "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent", it returns the correct path. In my case this is "C:\Documents and Settings\daniel.hilgarth\Recent".

Comment: its returning null values.Thats why.

Comment: @Nagendra: No, it doesn't. What user account are you execute your program with?

Comment: where does the recent files and folders will exist in xp?

Comment: See my answer. There is an example path.

Comment: Oh, so the problem is not actually that the **code** doesn't work. In fact, it works perfectly. You just don't believe that it's returning the correct folder because it's empty. Next time, look for the `user-error` tag. And, to think, I fired up a virtual machine just to check for any strange bugs...

Comment: Are "you" and "administrator account" the same?

Answer (score 0):

For getting recent file folder in Windows use the following command,

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
```